# Blender (and others) video editing: slow and/or bumpy playback - 100% CPU load

Tags: performance, cpu-load, video-editor, blender, playback

I use Blender for Video editing on Ubuntu 18.04, and whenever I playback the video I’m working on, the CPU load hits 100% and the playback is slow or bumpy or both.

This happens even if there is only one video strip in the timeline, with no effects at all, so it’s a simple playback that any media player (e.g. VLC, parole...) can do with no problems, but blender obviously can’t.

I tried different video editors. Openshot has the same playback issue.
Kdenlive does a fluent playback but tends to crash, and Avidemux does a fluent playback but is not powerful enough.

CPU: AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7
RAM 3500MB
Kernel version: 4.15.0-54-lowlatency

What’s wrong here?

thank you

Ole

Comment: You probably need to enable hardware acceleration in Blender - should be somewhere in "Preferences" > "System". You'll need to set "compute device" to OpenCl, and then select your graphics card.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t find that. This is my preferences -> system window: https://www.dropbox.com/s/93wtdojygivvx4r/Screenshot_2019-07-24_01-13-16.png?dl=0